# Помогите!!! Не выходит сделать кнопку со сложной анимацией!

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, анимация

Нужно сверстать такую кнопку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот ссылка на пример похожей кнопки и анимации ее границы https://rezart.agency/portfolio/artistream.ru/

Не выходит реализовать такую же анимацию, вот все что смог придумать

```css
.button {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #CC1414;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CC1414;
    padding: 11px 25px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: "CenturyGothic";
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
    transition: all .6s ease
}

.button:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 1px;
    background: #CC1414;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0
}

.button:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 1px;
    background: #CC1414;
    right: 0;
    top: 0
}

.button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none
}

.button:hover:before {
    bottom: 18px
}

.button:hover:after {
    top: 18px
}
```

```html
<a href="index.html" class="button no-page__button">Вернуться на гланую</a>
```

Comment: Это делается с помощью `SVG`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Кнопка в задаче выглядит несколько проще, чем в референсе, её можно в принципе и без svg сделать.

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 36px;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #cc1414;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button::before,
.button::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 150%;
  background: linear-gradient(-180deg, #cc1414 33.3%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 33.3%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 66.6%, #cc1414 66.6%);
  transition: transform .1s ease-out;
}

.button::before {
  left: 0;
  top: -50%;
}

.button::after {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.button:hover::before {
  transform: translateY(33.33%);
}

.button:hover::after {
  transform: translateY(-33.33%);
}
```

```html
<button class="button">
  Перейти в каталог
</button>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!)

Answer (score 4):

Вот более подходящий пример. Анимация данного эффекта в референсе работает не совсем корректно, при `:hover` добавляется `animation`, соответственно значения `stroke-dashoffset` & `stroke-dasharray` будут возвращаться в былое состояние, когда произойдёт `mouseleave`, что не является хорошей практикой.

Пример с сайта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Достаточно просто изменить `stroke-dashoffset` при `:hover`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #262626;
  border: 1px solid #979797;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

rect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  fill: none;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-dasharray: 180;
  stroke-dashoffset: 220;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

a:hover rect {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <span>StrokeDashOffset + StrokeDashArray</span>
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%"/>
  </svg>
</a>
```

Comment: в Лисе работает...:))

Comment: ты можешь посмотреть одну проблему ?

Comment: [смотри](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/OEEgBE?editors=1100) как убрать эти пиксели ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, давай продолжим в SVG_чате=)